# When calling into C from MIPS do we use JR or JALR?

Tags: c, mips, calling-convention, mips32

I'm writing some self-modifying code and I want to call a C function (call it `foo`) from MIPS.

I've loaded the mem add of `foo`, `&foo` into `$t1`. Now I `jr/jalr $t1`.

Will C set `$ra` as my current PC(+8) (before the jump) allowing me to use `JR` or will I have to `JALR` instead (ie, take care of it because C won't)?

I can't test this right now as I'm debugging my macros (for the MIPS mnemonics). I must have messed some up because I keep getting illegal instruction errors.

Comment: Just to make sure, but your C is compiled as MIPS right?

Comment: What  compiler are you using?

Comment: @SethCarnegie, I'm using sourcery codebench lite, which unless I'm mistaken is a modified gcc build and running on an OVP Malta (which is a MIPS board that can run linux) simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `JALR`.  How could the C function possibly know how to set `$ra` for you?